# Rich text editor cross-platform

Tags: windows-7, macos, text-editors, ipad, cross-platform

I'm about to write a thesis and I need to work on it on various devices: a MacBook Pro, a laptop with Windows 7 and an iPad. The problem is to find a way to keep in sync everything. I though of many solutions but nothing seems to be really helpful:

- **Pages**: it doesn't exist on Windows and it'd be a problem to keep in sync (iCloud works only between iPad and Mac, and not really smoothly with the latest);
- ***.doc* / *.otd* and Dropbox**: this could do the job on Windows and OS X but not on the iPad (since I could only open/edit the files without the possibility to save the back to Dropbox; maybe there's an app for that?);
- **Google Docs**: it seems the only way, but it's a webapp, therefore I don't trust it very much (both on the laptops and the iPad);

I don't actually need a lot of formatting since the layout will be defined as soon as I finish writing, but I still need some of it, so I can't rely on plain text editors.

Has some any better (and cheap :P) idea?